# Can I hide classes in the global namespace in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

In a visual studio 2008 solution, I have two versions of the same class in two different namespaces.

In VB, if I do this:

```
imports MyNamespace
' ...
dim x as DuplicatedClass = new DuplicatedClass()
```

it uses MyNamespace.DuplicatedClass instead of the globally-namespaced DuplicatedClass.  Meanwhile, in C#, doing this:

```
using MyNamespace;
// ...
DuplicatedClass x = new DuplicatedClass();
```

uses the globally-namespaced DuplicatedClass.  To use the other version, I have to use `MyNamespace.DuplicatedClass`.

I realize this is a problematic setup, but I can't change it.  Is there a way to prevent C# from seeing the globally namespaced class, or to specifically un-load it, or...?  Given how many classes are in the global namespace, being forced to choose the namespace every time could get pretty time-costly.

Comment: Are these Classes defined in separate assemblies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the best you could do is create a using alias:

```
//create alias
using defDuplicatedClass = MyNamespace.DuplicatedClass;

defDuplicatedClass x = new defDuplicatedClass();
```

The alias is file scoped.  So you'd have to repeat it at the top of each file as needed, but perhaps that is better than repeating a namespace with every occurance of DuplicatedClass.

Comment: Link to an example article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d(VS.80).aspx

Comment: That works excellently, thanks!  Didn't know about the alias feature.  Apparently it can't override the global namespaced class, but that's wholly acceptable.